# GTM Enhanced Ecommerce - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'purchase' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, enhanced-ecommerce, conversion-tracking

I am trying to get data like revenue, order value etc using the following code.
Upon checking in the console I receive: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'purchase' of undefined"

```js
var revenue = 0;
var shipping = 0;
var tax = 0;
var orderID = 0;
var orderValue = 0;
var couponCode = "";

if (typeof dataLayer !== undefined && dataLayer.length > 0 && typeof dataLayer.ecommerce !== undefined) {
  orderID = dataLayer[0].ecommerce.purchase.actionField.id;

  revenue = parseInt(dataLayer[0].ecommerce.purchase.actionField.revenue) > 0 ? parseInt(dataLayer[0].ecommerce.purchase.actionField.revenue) : 0;

  shipping = parseInt(dataLayer[0].ecommerce.purchase.actionField.shipping) > 0 ? parseInt(dataLayer[0].ecommerce.purchase.actionField.shipping) : 0;

  tax = parseInt(dataLayer[0].ecommerce.purchase.actionField.tax) > 0 ? parseInt(dataLayer[0].ecommerce.purchase.actionField.tax) : 0;

  couponCode = dataLayer[0].ecommerce.purchase.actionField.coupon;

  orderValue = revenue - (shipping + tax);
}
```

Comment: if dataLayer is an array shouldnt the check be `typeof dataLayer[0].ecommerce !== undefined`? or is it just a typo?

Comment: Updated the line to : if (typeof dataLayer !== undefined && dataLayer.length > 0 && typeof dataLayer[0].ecommerce !== undefined) - however i still get the same error message :/

Comment: what do you get if you console log `dataLayer`?

Comment: The following: 

(2) [{…}, {…}, push: ƒ]
0:
pagePostAuthor: "grafikfabriken"
pagePostType: "page"
pagePostType2: "single-page"
__proto__: Object
1:
event: "gtm.js"
gtm.start: 1594382014744
gtm.uniqueEventId: 0
__proto__: Object
2: {event: "gtm.dom", gtm.uniqueEventId: 8}
push: ƒ ()
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)

Answer (score 0):

To access object from **Google Tag Manager** you have to substitute the square brackets with dots. So classic JavaScript `Array[0].name` becomes `Array.0.name`.

A practical example is in Ecommerce tracking. To get the SKU of the first product in an ecommerce.purchase object (Enhanced Ecommerce), you'd use this in a Data Layer Variable:

```
ecommerce.purchase.products.0.id
```

That retrieves the value stored in the id key of the first product in the products Array of the Enhanced Ecommerce purchase object.

https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/access-array-members-in-the-data-layer/